# jQuery function to find class and fadeToggle another div with same class

Tags: jquery

I'm working on e-commerce site where I'm trying to make it so that when a list item displaying a category name is clicked, the relevant product category (in the 'product-display' div) will fadeToggle.
Both the list item and div I wish to fadeToggle have the same class name assigned.

How could I make this happen through jQuery?

```
<ul id="product-filter">
 <li class="cat_1">category 1</li>  // Clicking on this li item...
 <li class="cat_2">category 2</li>
</ul>

<div id="product-display">
  <div class="cat_1">  // fadeToggles this div
    <img src="image1.gif">
</div>

  <div class="cat_2">
    <img src="image2.gif">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#product-filter li[class^=cat_]').click(function()
{
    $('#product-display div[class=' + $(this).attr('class') + ']')
        .fadeIn(); // or whatever fade logic you need
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
$('#product-filter li').click(function() {
    $('#product-display div.' + $(this).attr('class')).fadeToggle();
});
```

That is, on click of one of the li elements get its class and then select the appropriate matching item within "product-dislay".

Having said that, if it were my code I would not use class to link the items, because it makes it kind of difficult to apply other classes to the li elements - I'd probably use a data attribute instead. For the product divs I'd probably use ids since they seem to be unique items:

```
<ul id="product-filter">
   <li data-category="cat_1">category 1</li>
   ...

<div id="product-display">
    <div id="cat_1">

$('#product-filter li').click(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('data-category')).fadeToggle();
});
```

Also I'd probably put anchor elements inside the li elements, because that way they can be "clicked" via the keyboard (for users who can't or don't use a mouse or other pointing device).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('#product-filter').find('li').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var item = $(this).attr('class');
        $('#product-display').find('.'+item).fadeToggle();
    });
});
```